# Ansible find if the server has websphere running on it or not

Tags: ansible

I'm in needing of help. I currently have to find if the server has websphere running on it or not. I can do it through ps -ef|grep websphere. Problem i'm facing is we can use only "raw" module as other modules wont run on old linux OS. I'm thinking of doing using the below code but not sure how to take the output of it and pass it in a file that gives server name and 0 or 1 where 0 is false and 1 is true.

```
---
  - name: To find the websphere servers
    hosts: websphere
    tasks:
      - name:
        raw: "if [[ $(ps aux | grep cron | grep -vc grep)  > 0 ]] ; then echo 1; else echo 0 ; fi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below approach.

```
- name: Getting process IDs of the process
  pids:
      name: cron
  register: cron_pids

- name: Printing the process IDs obtained
  debug:
    msg: "Process IDs of cron:{{cron_pids.pids|join(',')}}"

(OR)

You can use shell module to retrieve the info using registered variable

- name: Get running processes list from remote host
   shell: "ps -aux --no-headers | grep cron | awk '{print $2}'"
   register: running_processes

- debug:
       msg: "{{running_process}}"
```